# context value using the useContext in React is not accessible in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-context

I am making a project using the MERN stack, it is a ride hailing web app where the user can register as a driver or a rider and connect their Metamask wallet. Every time a user books a ride, the ride details are pushed to the MongoDB. These details are then fetched onto the driver dashboard component, the driver can accept which updates the Ride document in the database, adding the driver wallet address. Then, the driver can complete the ride which pushes a "status: 'complete'" to the database.

The problem is that when the driver completes the ride, I am able to get the updated document in the driverDashboard component, but I can't make it render in the riderDashboard component using the context library in React.

The driverDashboard and riderDashboard is rendered in the Home component.

My code is as follows.

Home.jsx :

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { RideContext } from "../context/RideContext";
import { UserContext } from "../context/UserContext";
import DriverDashboard from "./DriverDashboard";
import RiderDashboard from "./RiderDashboard";

function Home() {
  const { userInfo } = useContext(UserContext);

  if (userInfo?.typeOfUser === "rider") {
    return <RiderDashboard />;
  }
  if (userInfo?.typeOfUser === "driver") {
    return <DriverDashboard />;
  }
}

export default Home;
```

riderDashboard.jsx :

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { RideContext } from "../context/RideContext";
import RenderMap from "./RenderMap";
import Pricing from "./Pricing";
import axios from "axios";

function RiderDashboard() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState("");
  const [locationLat, setLocationLat] = useState(null);
  const [locationLon, setLocationLon] = useState(null);

  const [destinationLat, setDestinationLat] = useState(null);
  const [destinationLon, setDestinationLon] = useState(null);

  const [distance, setDistance] = useState("");

  async function handleChangeInLocation(e) {
    setLocation(e.target.value);
    setLoc(e.target.value);
  }

  async function handleChangeInDestination(e) {
    setDestination(e.target.value);
    setDest(e.target.value);
  }

  async function getLocationLatLong() {
    const response = await axios.get(`${fetchCoordinatesAPI}${location}`);
    const data = response.data[0];
    setLocationLat(Number(data.lat));
    setLocationLon(Number(data.lon));
  }

  async function getDestinationLatLong() {
    const response = await axios.get(`${fetchCoordinatesAPI}${destination}`);
    const data = response.data[0];
    setDestinationLat(Number(data.lat));
    setDestinationLon(Number(data.lon));
  }

  const { setLoc, setDest } = useContext(RideContext);

  const fetchCoordinatesAPI =
    "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=";

  async function handleClick() {
    getLocationLatLong();
    getDestinationLatLong();

    const accessToken = '<my_token>';
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.distancematrix.ai/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${location}&destinations=${destination}&key=${accessToken}`
    );
    const data = response.data;
    const distance = data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
    setDistance(distance / 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex mt-[80px] grid grid-cols-3 h-full">
      <div className="border-r-2 w-full p-6">
        <h1 className="font-black text-2xl mb-6">Where do you want to go.</h1>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <label
            for="base-input"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 text-xl"
          >
            From:
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChangeInLocation}
            placeholder="Enter pickup location"
            type="text"
            id="base-input"
            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 "
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-6">
          <label
            for="base-input"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 text-xl"
          >
            To:
          </label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChangeInDestination}
            placeholder="Enter drop location"
            type="text"
            id="base-input"
            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 "
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-6">
          <button
            className="w-full p-4 border bg-black text-white rounded-xl"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Check.
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="border-r-2 w-full">
        <RenderMap
          lat={locationLat}
          lon={locationLon}
          destLat={destinationLat}
          destLon={destinationLon}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="w-full">
        <Pricing distance={distance} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RiderDashboard;
```

driverDashboard.jsx :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { WalletContext } from "../context/WalletContext";
import { RideContext } from "../context/RideContext";

function DriverDashboard() {
  const { walletConnected, walletId } = useContext(WalletContext);
  const [driverLocationCoords, setDriverLocationCoords] = useState([]);
  const [driverLocationName, setDriverLocationName] = useState("");
  const [allRides, setAllRides] = useState(null);
  const { acceptedRideId, setAcceptedRideId, rideInfo, setRideInfo } =
    useContext(RideContext);
  const eth_logo = "https://cryptologos.cc/logos/ethereum-eth-logo.svg?v=024";

  const testLocation = [28.461, 77.4969];

  //   useEffect(() => {
  //     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  //       setDriverLocationCoords([
  //         position.coords.latitude,
  //         position.coords.longitude,
  //       ]);
  //     });
  //   }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/get-rides")
      .then((response) => console.log(setAllRides(response.data)));
  }, []);

  async function acceptRide() {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/update-driver-wallet-id",
      { id: acceptedRideId, driverWalletId: walletId }
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    setRideInfo(response.data);
  }

  async function completeTrip() {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/complete-ride", {
      id: acceptedRideId,
      status: "completed",
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    setRideInfo(response.data);
  }

  //   async function getLocationOfDriver() {
  //     const response = await axios.get(
  //       `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=${driverLocationCoords[0]}&lon=${driverLocationCoords[1]}&format=json`
  //     );
  //     setDriverLocationName(response.data.display_name);
  //   }

  return (
    <div className="mt-16 justify-center item-center p-12 w-full h-full">
      <div className="border rounded-xl h-96 w-96 p-8 bg-black text-white w-max">
        <h1 className="font-sans text-2xl mb-4"> Dashboard </h1>
        <div className="border-b-2 border-slate-600 mb-4"></div>
        <div>
          {/* <button onClick={getLocationOfDriver}> Click </button> */}
        </div>
        {rideInfo?.status == "completed" || !rideInfo ? (
          <div>
            {allRides?.map((ride) => {
              return (
                <div key={ride._id} className="flex gap-4 mb-4 items-center ">
                  <div>{ride._id}</div>
                  <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                    <img className="h-8 w-8" src={eth_logo} alt="eth_logo" />
                    <h1 className="font-2xl font-bold">{ride.price}</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div className="border border-white"></div>
                  <div className="text-gray-400">
                    <p>
                      {ride.from} <b className="text-white ml-4 mr-4 "> to </b>
                      {ride.to}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      className="border rounded-xl px-4 py-1 hover:bg-white hover:text-black"
                      disabled={walletConnected ? false : true}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setAcceptedRideId(ride._id);
                        acceptRide();
                      }}
                    >
                      {walletConnected
                        ? "Accept"
                        : "Please connect wallet to accept ride."}
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div>
              <button
                className="rounded-xl border px-4 py-1 hover:bg-white hover:text-black"
                onClick={completeTrip}
              >
                Complete trip.
              </button>
            </div>

            <div>{acceptedRideId}</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DriverDashboard;
```

(server/api) index.js

```
app.post("/book-ride", async (req, res) => {
  const { price, tier, from, to, riderWalletId } = req.body;
  try {
    const rideDoc = await Ride.create({
      from,
      to,
      price,
      riderWalletId,
      tier,
    });
    res.json(rideDoc);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
});

app.get("/get-rides", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rides = await Ride.find({ status: null });
    res.json(rides);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/update-driver-wallet-id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id, driverWalletId } = req.body;
  try {
    const rideDoc = await Ride.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      { driverWalletId: driverWalletId },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.json(rideDoc);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/complete-ride", async (req, res) => {
  const { id, status } = req.body;
  try {
    const rideDoc = await Ride.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      { status: status },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.json(rideDoc);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});
```

RideContext.jsx (this is the context file in which the rideContext is created.)

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const RideContext = createContext({});

export default function RideContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState("");
  const [dest, setDest] = useState("");
  const [acceptedRideId, setAcceptedRideId] = useState("");
  const [rideInfo, setRideInfo] = useState(null);

  return (
    <RideContext.Provider
      value={{
        loc,
        dest,
        setLoc,
        setDest,
        acceptedRideId,
        setAcceptedRideId,
        rideInfo,
        setRideInfo,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </RideContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

When I try to console log the rideInfo, setRideInfo, acceptedRideId, setAcceptedRideId in the riderDashboard
it returns null or the value that I initialized these states with. The api endpoint returns the data correctly from the db but the I just can't seem to make it accessible to the riderDashboard component.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your component wrapped in RideContextProvider?

Comment: @Anton Yes, I have my app component wrapped in the RideContextProvider. I think I forgot to add the app component snippet to the question.